# How to get Country Code in django-countries

Tags: python, django, django-countries

How can I get country code with this library? I don't want to get for example "CO" for Colombia or "NZ" for New Zealand, I want 57 for Colombia, or 1 for USA, for example.

Comment: Do you mean country calling codes (phone prefix numbers)? `django-countries` is not providing that

Comment: Exactly, I mean calling codes. It exists some library that give me this information?

Comment: Maybe you will find something useful in [python-phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) package

Answer (score 1):

Django-countries does not provide international dialling codes.

According to the [readme](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/blob/3dff4873b9350b3377498ef1b92810b705a59a26/README.rst), there is a `numeric` field, but that contains the [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric) code, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks, exists some library that allow me do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a library that does have that data.